# Use javascript auto sum and minus

Tags: javascript

Let say i want have 4 text box, the last textbox is for total. The first box i put 20, second box 20, and the last box is 10. If i sum up the total using the function updatesum(), it will make total 50. How about if i minus 10 without put '-10' in the text box'?

javascript:-

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--calculation-->
<!--
function updatesum() {
document.form.jumlah.value = (document.form.rm1.value -0) + (document.form.rm2.value -0) + (document.form.rm3.value -0) + (document.form.rm4.value -0) + (document.form.rm5.value -0) + (document.form.rm6.value -0) + (document.form.rm7.value -0) + (document.form.rm8.value -0) + (document.form.rm9.value -0) + (document.form.rm10.value -0) + (document.form.rm11.value -0) + (document.form.rm12.value -0) + (document.form.rm13.value -0) + (document.form.rm14.value -0) + (document.form.rm15.value -0);
}
//-->
</script>
```

html:-

```
<tr>
<td>13.</td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="d13" name="d13"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control calc" id="rm13" name="rm13"    onChange="updatesum()"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>14.</td>
   <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="d14" name="d14"></td>
   <td><input type="text" class="form-control calc" id="rm14" name="rm14" onChange="updatesum()"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>15.</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="d15" name="d15"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control calc" id="rm15" name="rm15" onChange="updatesum()"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td> 
    <td align="right">Total</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control calc" id="jumlah" name="jumlah" readonly value=""></td>
   </tr>
```

Comment: `How about if i minus 10 without put '-10' in the text box'?` Can you elaborate on it?

Comment: if i put 10 in the third box, it will sum the total into 50 right? If i put -10 in the third box, all will total up to 40. I wanted to try minus 10 without actually put '-'

Answer (score 1):

**Short and Sweet :**

Change `(document.form.rm15.value -0)` to `(document.form.rm15.value * -1)`

**Explanation :**

Each of the `(document.form.(name).value -0)` expressions are just converting the values that you are in the input boxes to numbers.  The `+` between each is adding them together.  Another option to convert them to numbers is to multiply them.  Since you are looking to subtract, and adding a negative is the same as subtracting, we can convert your value to a number, and invert it in one fell swoop, hence the `* -1`.

**Note :** You gave us more input boxes in JavaScript than you gave us in HTML, so I am just assuming that you have all of those inputs in your real world application.

**Note 2 :** There are certainly more concise ways to do this than writing out the full equation, but updating your methods was not in the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

change your `updatesum` method to

```
function updatesum()
{
        var total = 0;
        $('.calc:not(#jumlah)').each(function(){
          var value = $(this).val();
          //console.log("value " + value);
          if ( value.indexOf( "minus" ) != -1 )
          {
              value = -(parseFloat(value.replace( /minus/g, "" )));
              console.log("value " + value);
          }
          if ( String(value).length > 0 && !isNaN(value))
          {
            total += parseFloat(value);     
            //console.log(" running total " + total);
          }
        });
        console.log("total " + total);
        $('#jumlah').val(total);
}
```

Comment: @rees can you share a fiddle? what error is it showing now?

Comment: it doest show error but i appear nothing in the total. How do i share fiddle?

Comment: yes, thanks. but if i want to print, how do i make '-' diappear?

Comment: @rees didn't get you. what do you mean by making `-` disappear?

Comment: i mean if i entered 20,20,-10 and the total is 50. if i want to print the whole table, that (-10) will appear with '-', right?

Comment: @rees so how do you want it to behave? In your original question you didn't mentioned anything about making `-` disappear.

Comment: it's alright. Anyways , thanks a lot for helping me. I appreciate that.